# Error "HTTP 403 The website declined to show this webpage" in Excel vba while navigating URL

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel vba,I am trying to navigate an URL and fetch table data from specified url.

First, I hardcoded the URL

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=VGUARD&instrument=OPTSTK&strike=195.00&type=CE&expiry=29JUN2017"
```

This worked fine and I got the table data in excel.

Now I wanted to take **underlying** and **strike** (see url) from 2 seperate comboboxes(ComboBox1 and ComboBox2) in my worksheet.

So I changed the url as

```
ie.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=" & ComboBox1.Value & "instrument=OPTSTK&strike=" & ComboBox2.Value & ".00" & "&type=CE&expiry=29JUN2017"
```

But it is giving me an 
**Error**:::      **HTTP 403 The website declined to show this webpage**

How can I fix it ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the additional ampersand before instrument:

```
ComboBox1.Value & "instrument=OPTSTK&strike="
```

should be

```
ComboBox1.Value & "&instrument=OPTSTK&strike="
```

(FYI - you can't "fix" a HTTP error, that's generated by the server which you have no control over)